# get role of user in a string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, role

is there a way i can get the role in a string variable using the below commands....

```
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
  System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal wp = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(wi);
```

i need this for

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,                          // version
                                                   UserName.Text,           // user name
                                                   DateTime.Now,               // creation
                                                   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),// Expiration
                                                   false,                      // Persistent 
                                                   role);         // User data
```

as string role=  wp.IsInRole();
but this is not right

something similar to this...

Answer (score 6):

You can get a list of groups/roles that a user is part of from the WindowsIdentity.Groups property.  The WindowsIdentity.Groups collection only contains the SID's (collection of IdentityReference) of the groups/roles a user is in, but not the actual names of the groups/roles.  I will show you how to get the actual names of all the groups/roles a user is in.

First, get the WindowsIdentity object.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Second, use LINQ to translate the SID's (IdentityReference) to NTAccount's.

```
var groups = from sid in identity.Groups select sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

You can then loop through the groups and store them in a string array that can be used in the FormsAuthenticationTicket.  This will get you both the BUILTIN (local computer) groups/roles and also DOMAIN groups/roles the user is in.

Answer (score 4):

For getting Roles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getrolesforuser.aspx

Use `Roles.GetRolesForUser()`  or `Roles.GetRolesForUser(Page.User.Identity.Name)` to get an array of the roles the current user has. You can specify which user you want to get the roles for by `Roles.GetRolesForUser("Specific UserName")`

You can use `String.Join(", ",Roles.GetRolesForUser())` to get a string of roles the user has.

`String.Join` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing apples and oranges. Are you using Windows or Forms authentication?

In either case, you can get the user's roles from the RoleProvider, if it is implemented.

Examining the thread's current principal only exposes a check method, as you know, IsInRole, whereas the role provider will return a string array of roles the user belongs to.

But I have to ask why you are packing a role(s) into the ticket? The only valid use case I can see for this is you are consolidating external auth/role silos.

If you explain your scenario and requirements a bit more fully I am sure we can find a specific solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like so?

```
public static string FormsAuthUserData
{
    get
    {
        IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        if (principal == null) return null;
        FormsIdentity identity = principal.Identity as FormsIdentity;
        if (identity == null) return null;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = identity.Ticket;
        return ticket == null ? null : ticket.UserData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Forms Authentication seems to clash with Windows Identities, but I have written some code which I believe will do what you ask.

First of all, add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices` to your project.

You need to initialize a `PrincipalContext` object first.

`imports System.DirectoryServices`

`Dim userImLookingFor as AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(ctx)`
`Dim tempUser As New AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(ctx)`
`tempUser.SamAccountName = p_samAccountName`
`Dim searcher As New AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher(tempUser)`
`If searcher.FindAll().Count = 1 Then`
`userImLookingFor = searcher.FindAll()(0)`

When this code runs, `userImLookingFor` contains the user specified by p_samAccountName.  Next, you want to get a list of the groups.

`Dim tempGp As New AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal(userImLookingFor.Context)`
`Dim searcher As New AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher(tempGp)`
`Dim searchResult As AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult(Of AccountManagement.Principal)`
`searchResult = searcher.FindAll()`

Finally, you may refer to the searchResult collection.  To get the group names, enumerate through the indexes and and retrieve either the "User Principal Name" or the "SAM Account Name".

Yup, Forms Authentication does not play that well with Active Directory, but let me know if this helps.  I am not familiar with the approach in the previous answer; these two different answers may give you objects that give you access to different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a extension method to your user class, to get the collection of all Roles in the system (asking your Role provider) do a cicle (or use linq) to ask the isInRole foreach role and collect the user Roles in a property ready to use.

That can be a way generic to any type of Role provider.